# Filesystem implementation in F#

Tags: f#

I'm coming from C# background and have just started learning F#.
I seem to be stuck on an assignment that seems rather simple.

I need to implement a filesystem with the GIVEN (changing it is not an option) type where 'a is meant for names and 'b for data.

```
type Tree<'a,'b> = Node of list<'a * Tree<'a,'b>>
                 | Leaf of 'b
```

Filesystem would then be an instance of this type where file/directory names are given by strings 'a and the file contents by strings 'b. Directories should be nodes and files leaves.

```
type FileSystem = Tree<string,string>

// / (directory)
// /home (directory)
// /home/.emacs (file)
// /home/.ssh (directory)
// /home/.ssh/id_rsa (file)
// /usr  (directory)
// /usr/bin (directory)
// /usr/bin/bash (file)
// /usr/bin/emacs (file)
```

I am stuck at...

```
let fs = Node["/",
             Node["home",
                 Node[".ssh",
                     Node["id_rsa", Leaf("id_rsa_DATA")]
                     ]  
                 ]
              ]
```

Any attempt to add more nodes or leaves to any of the nodes fails as compiler expects a tree and not a list?
What is the proper syntax to build a tree like this?

With this tree I need to implement:

```
ls : FileSystem -> list<string>  // list root directory
subfs : FileSystem -> list<string> -> FileSystem // return the filesystem you find at that path
ls' : FileSystem -> list<string> -> list<string> // list data of directory files at given path (fail if its just a file)
```

Edit:

So this is it:

```
let fs = Node["/", 
              Node["home/",
                    Node[".ssh/",
                         Node["id_rsa", Leaf("id_rsa_DATA")
                             ];
                   ".emacs", Leaf(".emacs_DATA")
                   ];
                   "usr/",
                    Node["bin/",
                          Node["bash", Leaf("bash_DATA");
                               "emacs", Leaf("emacs_DATA")
                              ];
                   ".emacs", Leaf(".emacs_DATA")];
                  ]
             ]
```

Now how can I list directories and subfilesystem (ls, subfs, ls')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have you list elements (the `'a * Tree<'a,'b>`) be a `string * Node` for a directory (or sub-directory), and a `string * Leaf` for a file.

That way you'd end up with something like this:

```
type Tree<'a,'b> = 
    | Node of list<'a * Tree<'a,'b>>
    | Leaf of 'b

let fs = Node["/", 
               Node ["someFile.txt", Leaf("content");
                     "aFile.txt", Leaf("some content");
                     "someDir/",
                       Node [ "anotherFile.txt", Leaf("more content");
                              "script.sh", Leaf("script content")      ];
                     "logfile.log", Leaf("log content") ] ]
```

Comment: But the entire Node must be a list. It's a project requirement and I can't change it.

Comment: Whoops, misread the type. I updated it for lists, instead of lone tuples.

Comment: Okay, after using F# Interactive, I finally got it right, I think. :)

Comment: Thanks. This is it. How would I use this to list directories and subfilesystems (with data) at a given pats?

Comment: I would approach it as an algorithm that traverses the tree. [Try Depth-First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), as it can be done recursively. (You'll need to adapt this for `Leaf` elements.)

Answer (score 1):

Is this closer to what you want?

That is, each node is a tuple of some value 'a and a list of children of type Tree<'a,'b>?

```
type Tree<'a,'b> = 
  | Node of 'a * Tree<'a,'b> list
  | Leaf of 'b

let fs = Node("/",
               [Node("home",
                       [Node(".ssh",
                               [Node("id_rsa", 
                                  [Leaf("id_rsa_DATA")]
                               )]
                       )]
               )]
             )

let rec f n =
  match n with
  | Node(".ssh",nodeList)::tail -> 
      printfn "found .ssh"
      f tail
      f nodeList
  | Leaf(leafStr)::tail -> 
      printfn "found leaf %s" leafStr
      f tail

f [fs]
```

The recursive cases for this structure are a little bit more complicated to work with than it needs to be, so... you might like this definition better:

```
type Tree<'a,'b> = 
  | Node of 'a * Tree<'a,'b> list
  // omit the leaf and define it as a node with an empty list of children
```

Unless of course you would like to be more explicit about what you are working with:

```
type FileSys<'a,'b> = 
  | Folder of 'a * FileSys<'a,'b> list
  | File of 'b
```

and if we are talking about a system of file and folder labels, does it need to be generic?

```
type FileSys = 
  | Folder of string * FileSys list
  | File of string
```

Often going towards a solution that makes use of discriminated unions in preference to generic types is the simpler way to go.  If you do that, you are putting more trust in FSharp's rich set of structures and pattern matching rather than first building up a generic set of tools so that you can subsequently reason about your problem.  With F# reasoning and making tooling around your problem space can happen at the same time, in an exploratory fashion.

Comment: Actually Tree Node should be defined exactly as a list<'a * Tree<'a,'b>>